# How to get the instance of RememberMeServices?

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I need to generate a `remember-me`-token outside of SpringSec's web-filter. I know I can copy&paste the code from `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` or instantiate it directly, but I would rather like to reuse the existing instance.

How can I get a hold of RememberMeServices instance from `springSecurityService` or `grailsApplication`?

Comment: Did you try to inject RememberMeServices bean using, for example, @Autowired annotation in your service?

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourController{

   def rememberMeServices // this autowires it into your controller

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.